# parse html page for pagination using dom

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I wanna parse this html page, to make pagination :

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_PaperList_PageNavigator" class="page-navigator">
<a id="ctl00_MainContent_PaperList_Prev" title="Go to Previous Page" class="nextprev"  
   href="/Search?query=text%20summarization&amp;s=0&amp;start=1&amp;end=10">Previous<a>
<a href="s&#61;0&#38;start&#61;1&#38;end&#61;10">1</a> <span class="current">2</span>
<a id="ctl00_MainContent_PaperList_Next" title="Go to Next Page" class="nextprev" 
href="/ Search?query=text%20summarization&amp;s=0&amp;start=21&amp;end=30">Next</a>
<div>
```

For the previous page, I need to parse the previous page and go to next page. here's the code :

```
$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('');
if($link = $html->find('div[class=page-navigator] ')) {  
    $previous = $link->first_child()->href; 
    $next     = $link->last_child()->href;
    $html->clear();  
    unset($html);  
    // other process
}
```

I still get error `Fatal error: Call to a member function first_child() on a non-object in D:\AppServ\www\coba\page\page1.php on line 18`

what's wrong. thank you :)

Comment: What about `var_dump($link)`, what does that give you?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it gives `array(1) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2844 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(1) ["tag"]=> string(3) "div" ["attr"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(41) "ctl00_MainContent_PaperList_PageNavigator" ["class"]=> string(14) "page-navigator" } ["children"]=> array(10) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2846 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(1) ["tag"]=> string(4) "span" ["attr"] ...`

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your xpath:

```
 if($link = $html->find("div[class='page-navigator'] ")) {  
                        ^--        ^--            ^--^--
```

note the changes in the quoting. You're getting an error back instead of a domnodelist, and the error object has no first_child() method.

Comment: still return `Fatal error: Call to a member function first_child() on a non-object in D:\AppServ\www\coba\page\page1.php on line 19`

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do:

```
if($link = $html->find('div.page-navigator')) {
```

Comment: still return `Fatal error: Call to a member function first_child() on a non-object in D:\AppServ\www\coba\page\page1.php on line 19`

Comment: @bruine if you you do: echo($html) just after  file_get_html call, what does it have?

Comment: the web page of the web that I parse